# Import date from CSV File to teradata table

Tags: csv, import, teradata

I need to import data containing 2 dates from a CSV file to a teradata volatile table using BTEQ.
I use the following script :

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE tab1,
NO FALLBACK ,      
NO BEFORE JOURNAL,      
NO AFTER JOURNAL,      
CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,      
DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO  (  
ent DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL, 
eng DECIMAL(7,0), 
dat_deb DATE, 
dat_fin DATE,  
ad_id DECIMAL(8,0),
id_lig DECIMAL(6,0),
Cd_a DECIMAL(7,0),
va_n DECIMAL(3,0),
satu DECIMAL(3,0)
)  
PRIMARY INDEX (ent, eng,ad_id,id_lig) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

then i import to the created table the following data :

```
.IMPORT VARTEXT ';' FILE="C:\Desktop\fichiertest.csv"  , SKIP=1; 
.REPEAT *

.SET QUIET ON;

USING(
ent DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL, 
eng DECIMAL(7,0), 
dat_deb DATE, 
dat_fin DATE,  
ad_id DECIMAL(8,0),
id_lig DECIMAL(6,0),
cd_a DECIMAL(7,0),
va_n DECIMAL(3,0),
satu DECIMAL(3,0)
)

INSERT INTO tab1(
ent, 
eng, 
dat_deb , 
dat_fin ,  
ad_id, 
id_lig,
cd_a,
va_n,
satu 
) 
      VALUES (  
:ent, 
:eng, 
CAST(:dat_deb AS DATE), 
CAST(:dat_fin AS DATE),  
:ad_id, 
:id_lig,
:cd_a,
:va_n,
:satu  
      );
```

but I have a problem with the dates:  *** Failure 2665 Invalid date.

could you help me solve this error

Comment: When you define VARTEXT all input columns must be defined as `VARCHAR(..)`. Additionally you should avoid single rows inserts by applying a high `PACK`, e.g. `.REPEAT * PACK 1000 ...`

Answer (score 0):

I've spent the last few hours trying to get a csv file loaded into Teradata.  I kept encountering the 2665 error.  To solve the issue, I learned that the dates saved in a csv file must be formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

So I reformatted my data using the format cells option in excel and then re-saved the csv.

I ran my create table query where I cast my date column as a date as follows:
, CREATION_DT DATE NOT NULL

Before importing my csv into Teradata, I went in the Teradata SQL Assistant and from the menu I selected Tools >> Options >> Data Format and then changed the Display Dates in this format option to the 2009-12-25 option. Finally, I ran my import query.

Hope this helps! Happy mining!!